# What is a secure and efficient method for website users to reset their password?

Tags: email, passwords, usability

Many sites implement different methods and I am having a hard time deciding on which method would work best for my site.

My user profiles contain the following data:

```
username
password (in hash/digest form)
email
```

I'd like the password reset method to be secure, user-friendly, and efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add two fields, reset_code and reset_expiry

This is the process for a secure password reset functionality.

- User selects "Forgot password".
- User prompted for email/username.
- If valid, generates a GUID, and stores it in reset_code and also stores Now()+24 hours in reset_expiry in the database against that particular user.
- Then it sends an email to the email address with a link to confirm the password reset. This email would contain a link to your website with the user's username AND reset_code embedded. (This stops a malicious user resetting a third parties password just by knowing their email)
- Once the user clicks on the link in the email, they will be directed to your website.
  Your website will validate that: the username and reset_code matches, and the current time hasn't exceeded the reset_expiry time.
- If all is okay, we can complete the password reset. This can be done by either:
  a) Onscreen a new randomly generated password
  b) A new randomly generated password via email
  c) The ability to enter a password of his/her own choosing

Comment: If using randomly generated password be sure to adjust the complexity to match the ability of your users. i.e. Don't use lots of non-alphanumerics if not ally your users are computer savvy. Also be sure to trim whitespace from the entered passwords as they'll likely be cut-n-pasted from emails, which often picks up extra whitespace.

Comment: Some character restrictions and substitutions are good ideas too: remove `{0,1,2,3,5,l}` from the character list, down-case everything, and apply a map like `[0,1,2,3,5,l] -> [o,i,z,b,s,i]` to the password you get back from the user. "3" is there because "B" is often mistaken for "3" when there is no familiar context, the others should be clear.

Answer (score 7):

You should not store the passwords of your users, not even in encrypted form. You should only store the hash/digest necessary for authentication. Then, you can't "recover" the password (because you don't know it), you can just reset it, and/or give the user a temporary one-time password that allows him to set a new password.

*Update*: if you are doing the above, the standard procedure is to have a "require-password-reset" form. The user enters his id (typically his email) and a "token" (eg, a random string) is generated, stored in some table with some expiration date, and sent to his email along with a link to the "password-reset" form. In this form the token is checked,  the user is allowed to enter a new password, and instructed to attempt a new login.

*Update 2*: A small privacy issue might arise: What should we do if the user id (email, user name, or whatever) entered in the request form does not exist in our database? To output a message *"User does not exist. Check the id and retry."* may be ok, but in some cases it would cause a privacy problem: anyone can check if other someone is registered in your database! If you want to avoid that, you must output the same message ("a mail has been sent with instructions...") even if the user wasnt found (and hence a mail was not actually sent).
Similar privacy issues advise to just output the message *"login incorrect : bad user or password"* when the user tries to login unsuccessfully - don't disclose if it was an incorrect user or password.

Comment: I apologize, I do actually store the hash/digest, by recover i meant reset :)

Comment: +1. @Absolute0: Think about what happens if someone steals your password database. If the passwords are hashed, then no great loss (you're already been 0wned, but at least the attacker can't user the password database for anything). If you store the passwords, however, and if your users use the same password for your site as for their email (and they will) then they will blame you when their email also gets hacked...

Comment: @Absolute0: Crossed over with your comment - glad to hear you're doing the right thing :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Leonbloy.  Storing the password leads to trouble like the Gawker incident from a few weeks ago (1.5 million userid/pwd combinations were discovered and published).

You should, however, have a "reset password" function that e-mails the new password to the original e-mail address used to open the account.

There should be no provision for changing the e-mail address during the password reset.  If the user doesn't have access to the old e-mail account anymore, too bad. Abandon the account and start over.

And use a good Captcha on the reset screen.